# Getting Kivy to update Async image with Clock

Tags: python-2.7, kivy

I have several screens run by ScreenManager, and on one I have an image that is loaded with an image taken from a URL (for weather). My issue is, I can't seem to quite get the URL & image updated periodically:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock
import pyowm

class Weather(Screen):
    addr = StringProperty()

    def wx_forecast(self):
        owm = pyowm.OWM('******************')
        observation = owm.weather_at_place('London,uk')
        w = observation.get_weather()
        i = w.get_weather_icon_name()
        addr = str("http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + i + ".png")
        print(addr)
        return addr

    def update(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.ids.wxlabel.source, 45)
    #def update(self):
        #self.wx_forecast()
        #Clock.schedule_interval(lambda dt: self.ids.wxlabel, 30)

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass

smsettings = Builder.load_string( """
ScreenManagement:
    Weather:

<Weather>:
    name: 'weather'
    FloatLayout:
        BoxLayout:
            AsyncImage:
                id: wxlabel
                source: root.wx_forecast()
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 30
            Button:
                text: 'Change Location'
                on_press:
            Button:
                text: 'More Details'
                on_release:
""" )

class HomeUtilities(App):
    def build(self):
        return smsettings

if __name__=='__main__':
    HomeUtilities().run()
```

Where the `def update` is where I am having issues; I have tried calling the function `wx_forecast` again, even trying another function outside the `Weather` class, but all it says is `str: has no attribute 'wx_forecast'`

So I believe I am on the right lines? Or I could be completely mistaken, but nothing I try seems to work. Even putting `self.ids.wxlabel.source.sunny.png` brings up `str: has no attribute image` but the file is there.

Comment: I don't fully understand yuor question, but the Clock.schedule_interval line is wrong (your lambda function doesn't do anything), and `self.ids.wxlabel.source.sunny.png` doesn't make any sense (the source doesn't have a property called `sunny` - you want something like `self.ids.wxlabel.source = 'sunny.png'`.

Comment: Can you post a runnable example demonstrating the problem?

Comment: Hi inclement, I can't get to an online computer at the moment, but will post runnable example shortly.

Comment: Basically, I wan't to reload an image widget periodically, with the image being an AsyncImage with the address given by wx_forecast. Unfortunately also tried your method and was handed the error lamda cannot contain assignment. Will be in touch, thank you in advance

Comment: Hi inclement, sorry it has taken so long for me to get round to this edit, but the file should be runnable now; hope you or anyone else reading this can help and it makes sense what I'm trying to achieve